# Production React App Failing With 429 Error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nginx, amazon-ec2, http-status-code-429

I have built a react app webpage, i **use node, express and react. I serve it within an ec2 ubuntu server with nginx**, i also installed ssl and configured DNS but when I load the page, the first time it gives no problems, but when reloaded, i get this [Server responded with 429 status code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8Xi8.png)

The page is very simple itself, but stills failing and i can't solve the problem, i have read a lot of posts and blogs to fix it but none has worked (this only happens in production, in dev environment i get no error when running my node app).

Some of those said that you had to lazy load images and i did it, i have also tried loading components in timeout so requests are made every 1.5 seconds...

The main files that give me problems are the **manifest.json** and **favicon.ico**, they are accesible by url so i can't understand why ([another 429 example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpo58.png)).

### Node server.js

> Routes has nothing, just console logs

```
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const path = require("path");
const cors = require("cors");

const allowedOrigins = [`http://localhost:${process.env.PORT}`];

var corsOptions = {
  origin: function (origin, callback) {
    if (allowedOrigins.indexOf(origin) !== -1 || !origin) {
      callback(null, true)
    } else {
      callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'))
    }
  }
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.json());

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/public")));

app.use("/", require("./routes/routes"));
app.get("*", (_, res) => res.redirect("/"))

app.listen(process.env.PORT, function () {
  console.log(`Listening on port ${process.env.PORT}`);
});
```

### App directory structure

[This is my folders structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKRLP.png), public folder is the build that react script `npm run build` returns.

### React app directory structure

[Here you can see the structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yw3iN.png), nothing special to what you get when run `npx create-react-app`. As you can see, there's a `favicon.ico` and `manifest.json`.

#### Manifest.json

```
{
  "short_name": "Proximedica Bajío",
  "name": "Proximedica Bajío - Oxígeno Medicinal",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "favicon.ico",
      "sizes": "64x64 32x32 24x24 16x16",
      "type": "image/x-icon"
    },
    {
      "src": "logo192.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "192x192"
    },
    {
      "src": "logo512.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "512x512"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": ".",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#000000",
  "background_color": "#ffffff"
}
```

This is all, if you need me to provide some other file it would be a pleasure.
Thanks!

Comment: You do have a route set up to handle requests for GET /, right?

Comment: Yes, in `routes.js` but is just a simple `res.json()`